# in Google Script create a function to call JSON data into an array and paste it in Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, parameters

I have a script that calls data from a JSON and paste it into rows of my Google Sheet.
The problem is that every row takes time so i want to paste XX rows at once instead of 1 by 1.

I'm trying to create some loops and the one i used here is just an example.
I get the right output in the logger  `[[content, content, content], [content2, content2, ...], ...]` but I also get this error

> Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 9.

So far this is the code (of loops)

```
var i = 0
parti = {}
var myarray = []
for ( var b = 3; b < 12 ; b++ ) {
var cellvalue = sh.getRange('HS'+b).getValue();
    try {
      parti[i] = [data[cellvalue]._genes.cls, data[cellvalue]._genes.eyes.d.partId, data[cellvalue]._genes.ears.d.partId, data[cellvalue]._genes.back.d.partId, data[cellvalue]._genes.mouth.d.partId, data[cellvalue]._genes.horn.d.partId, data[cellvalue]._genes.tail.d.partId]
    }
    catch (e) { 
       console.log(e)
    }
    
    myarray.push(parti[i])
    Logger.log(myarray)
    i = i + 1
  }



  sh.getRange('IA3:IG11').setValues([myarray]);
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.
There was an error in the `.setValues([myarray]);`
With `.setValues(myarray);` it works!